# how to calculate the bit-band alias fort bit 17 of address 0x4000 0100 in Cortex-M3?

Tags: cortex-m, bit-banding

How would one calculate the bit-band alias fort bit 17 of address 0x4000 0100 in Cortex-M3? Is this correct?

```
0x4200 0000 + 0X100*32 + 17*4 = 0x4200 2044
```

Comment: This looks correct to me.

Comment: if this is correct, the bit-band alias for bit 1 of address 0x4000 0102 is also 0x4200 2044. How could this be explained?

Comment: Because its the same thing! Bit 17 of 0x40000100 is bit 1 of 0x40000102. The address is of individual bytes (the bytes address). For example if 0x40000100 is treated as a 32bit word, then the 32bits are in 0x40000100, 101, 102 & 103.

Comment: I understand. Thx a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. This is correct. See the comments above.